# Non-static method should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context -Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have the following models.

**Venues Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Venues extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     ** @var string
     */

    protected $table = 'locations';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'country','city','client_id'];


    public function survey(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Survey', 'location_to_survey','location_id', 'survey_id')->withPivot('is_review');
    }

}
```

**Survey Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Survey extends Model
{
    //
    public function venues(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Venues', 'location_to_survey','location_id', 'survey_id')->withPivot('is_review');
    }
}
```

When I am trying to get the surveys of a venue, I am getting following error.

```
 $survey = Venues::survey()->where('id','=', $id)->orderBy('surveys.id','DESC' )->first();
```

> Non-static method App\Venues::survey() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

I have created Models and relations same like this in Laravel 5.1 without this issue. I want to know if I am missing something in Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`survey()` is a relation method that is definitely not static, I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish but you have tow options, you either get the survey you want directly from the `Survey` model like so:

```
Survey::where('id','=', $id)->orderBy('surveys.id','DESC' )->first();
```

or you do that on an instance of the `Venues` model like so:

```
$venue->survey()->where('id','=', $id)->orderBy('surveys.id','DESC' )->first();
```

and in the second case of course it will be searching through the surveys that belong that specific venue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the surveys of the venue, then you should do something like this...

```
$surveys = Venue::find($id)->venues()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()
```